# how to use keywords to search column in sql

Tags: mysql, select

I need to find all the songs which has 'ing' in **song_title**.

So, I write following code:

```
select *
from song
where song_title = 'ing'
```

But, that shows all the **song_title** which name is 'ing'.

How to get all that contain's 'ing' in **song_title**?

Comment: `select * from song where song_title like '%ing%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) operators for pattern matching as follows:

```
SELECT* FROM song WHERE song_title LIKE '%ing%'
```

If you want to select records that **start** with a certain string then you can use:

```
SELECT* FROM song WHERE song_title LIKE 'ing%'
```

If you want to select records that **end** with a certain string then you can use:

```
SELECT* FROM song WHERE song_title LIKE '%ing'
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a `LIKE` comparison, MySQL also has a REGEXP comparison operator. To return only rows where song_title contains the string `'ing'`

```
   WHERE song_title REGEXP 'ing'
```

---

With a `LIKE` comparison, the wild card characters are **`'%'`** to match any number (zero, one or more) of any character, and the underscore `'_'` to match one character.  To search for literal **`'%'`** or **`'_'`** character, those characters need to be escaped.

With the REGEXP, there's a whole boatload of characters that have special meaning. e.g. **`'^'`** matches the beginning of the string, **`'$'`** matches the end of the string, and the square brackets, and all those other characters frequently used in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

select * from song where song_title like '%ing%';

Use the like operator with substitution strings.